# How to create a git repository on a shared windows machine which all developers can push to

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-2013

I have created a bare Git repository on a shared windows machine on a local area network. I am experiencing a problem in which nobody else but me is able perform a push operation. When trying to sync with or push to the remote repository using the Visual Studio 2013 Git tools, other users receive an error reading "Opening repository: .The following errors were reported during push: refs/heads/master, Failed to rename lockfile to '/refs/heads/master': Access is denied." There seem to be a lot of similar questions about creating a shared repository on stack overflow though none of them have given me the right solution for my problem. One thought is that I may need to create a repository user group, perhaps based on our domain user groups, though I do not have any idea how to do this with Git on Windows and have not found any resources for instructions as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can share the folder that contains the bare git repository, and just add those Windows users as people who can read and write to those folders. After making a folder "shared" Windows should tell you what the network path should be. Then it's a simple `git clone file:////MACHINE_NAME/path/repo.git`.

Comment: This worked, thank you. I did not know the problem was this simple.